# Adding range in INDEX and RANDBETWEEN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Working formula:

> =INDEX({249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000},RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000)))

**Amendment needed**

`249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000` are fixed `INDEX` and can be easily `RANDBETWEEN`.

I want to add a range of `500 to 1500` in `INDEX` and `RANDBETWEEN`.

Is there any way to include the range of `500 to 1500` in this formula? If not then what is correct way to create a formula as per my needs.

Comment: This question makes no sense. What are you trying to accomplish in general?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.

In an empty column, type your numbers `249,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000`. I have removed `749` as it falls in the range `500-1500`. Next type `500, 501` and then drag it down to `1500`. Let's say you have them in Col A. You can also do this in a separate worksheet.

So if you start at `A1` then the values will go up to row `1008` as shown in the image below.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now use this formula

```
=INDEX(A1:A1008,RANDBETWEEN(1,1008))
```

Comment: why bother witht he countA() and not just hard code it to 1008 since the list is already set?

Comment: I could see the countA if you used the A:A for the index range.  Both are valid options...later is probably more generic.

Comment: True :) Not sure how I missed that :D

Comment: I personally going through the pains of a kidney stone, so maybe it was just me needing a distraction from the pain.   Have you had your morning coffee yet? 8)

Comment: Yeah I did but this is simply not acceptable. I should have seen it. BTW, I hope you feel better soon :)

Comment: Thank you so much Siddharth. It works. Is there any way without using column range as I described above in Excel?

Comment: Honestly Steve, i am not sure. I never had to do this :D. Let me experiment with it. If I come up with an answer, I will update the above post and leave a comment under your question.

Comment: not sure but if you typed in all the points into a static array you could dot it.  The problem is you would run out of characters.

Comment: Siddharth as your formula worked 100% correct. One thing can be done if I want? I need probability of the range of 500 up to 1500 up to 35%. It is because when I added formula and out of 1500+ rows I got other ranges only a few times. So when I will limit 500 up to 1500 range to 35% rest will be distributed in 65% automatically.

Comment: @SteveMethner based on you wanting to limit it to 35%, you can use my formula and set the first randbetween to  1,100 or just random() and set your comparison to <=35 or <=.35 depending on which option you choose.

Comment: @SteveMethner It was initially missing a closing bracket which has been added

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I was originally going to point out that you missed 749, but then I read your answer and see why you removed it.  Nice catch.  My method allows for it to come up more often since its in both options.  Something the OP would ultimately need to decide on.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(Randbetween(1,1009)<=1001,randbetween(500,1500),INDEX({249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000},randbetween(1,8)))
```

A random integer is determined between 1 and the number of possible numbers.  if it is less than or equal to the number in the sequential range 500 to 1500, which is 1001, then we tell then we use the randbetween (500,1500).  If the initial number if greater than our range, then we have it pull a random number from our supplied list of numbers.  8 is the number of supplied numbers in the static array.

Now if I recall correctly, randbetween is a volatile function.  As such anytime something in your work book changes, this formula will recalculate and provide a new number.

UPDATE:

Since you want to limit the 500-1500 range to 35% of the time, try using either of the formulas below:

```
=IF(Randbetween(1,100)<=35,randbetween(500,1500),INDEX({249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000},randbetween(1,8)))

=IF(Rand()<=0.35,randbetween(500,1500),INDEX({249,749,1999,4999,9999,10000,19999,50000},randbetween(1,8)))
```

Comment: Nice one... I am just thinking, what if the user later on wants to add another range say 2000 to 3000 and then 5000 to 6000 and then 12000 to 13000 and so on....

Comment: I had not got that far...depending on the number of subranges you could set up nested IFs or maybe use the CHOOSE function?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think it would probably better to assign a probability for winding up in each range, and then use a series of nested IFs with an new random and probability based on making it that far down the nested if.  If you are using helper cells and can break up the calculation you could use globabl probabilities for each range and just use one random number to find out what range you are in and then calculate based on that...just off the top of my head.

Comment: @ForwardEd, thank you so much. Your updated formula worked 100% as per my needs.